# Custom timeout for Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management

Tags: hyper-v, reboot, windows-server

Today, this is a second time recently when while trying to restart Windows Server 2016 host machine, it gets stuck on "*Shutting down service: Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management*" (yes, the virtual machine had been stuck, I saw it in the Hyper-V manager) for already some 20 minutes - I do not want to hard-reset the host.

Where can this too-long timeout be adjusted, please? Thanks! I would like to set it to some reasonable time (e.g. 20 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

This same problem is evoked in the post
[Server 2016 Running Hyper-V Stuck in "Shutting down service: Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management"](https://serverfault.com/questions/919868/server-2016-running-hyper-v-stuck-in-shutting-down-service-hyper-v-virtual-mac).

The summary of the answers :

- This can happen after a Windows Update to the VM.
  Wait for it to finish, even if it takes hours.
- RDP or SSH into the VM and use the
  [shutdown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown).

Some other answer in this post were not included here, because of
low pertinence.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, unfortunately, it does not solve anything. 1) I can't "wait hours" just because of some stuck update - there are users to work on the machine... I may wait at night, but not during work hours... 2) You cannot RDP into a machine which is already in shutting down process... So my question remains unanswered. Thanks for reply, though.

Comment: If waiting doesn't help, and RDP is not working, then I hope that you have a backup for the VM. You may forcefully stop it and restart, and perhaps Windows Update will recover/undo the update.

Comment: Yes, but this requires manual intervention, not optimal.